# local objective vs. shared global objective

Tags: scorm, scorm2004

Please see the following manifest. The Activity_1's primary objective has mapInfo refers to
a Shared Global Objective with objective id = gObj-OB01a, but there is not any objective with objective id = gObj-OB01a. Is this manifest correct or not?

```
<organization identifier = "Course_1">
     <title>Course 1 </title>
     <item identifier = "activity_1" identifierref = "SEQ01">
        <title>Activity 1</title>
        <imsss:sequencing>
           <imsss:objectives>
              <imsss:primaryObjective objectiveID = "PRIMARYOBJ_1" >
                 <imsss:mapInfo targetObjectiveID = "gObj-OB01a" writeSatisfiedStatus = "true" />
              </imsss:primaryObjective>
           </imsss:objectives>
        </imsss:sequencing>
     </item>
     <item identifier = "activity_2" identifierref = "SEQ01">
        <title>Activity 2</title>
        <imsss:sequencing>
           <imsss:sequencingRules>
              <imsss:preConditionRule>
                 <imsss:ruleConditions>
                    <imsss:ruleCondition condition = "satisfied"/>
                 </imsss:ruleConditions>
                 <imsss:ruleAction action = "skip"/>
              </imsss:preConditionRule>
           </imsss:sequencingRules>
           <imsss:objectives>
              <imsss:primaryObjective objectiveID = "PRIMARYOBJ_2" >
                 <imsss:mapInfo targetObjectiveID = "gObj-OB01a" />
              </imsss:primaryObjective>
           </imsss:objectives>
        </imsss:sequencing>
     </item>
     <item identifier = "activity_3" identifierref = "SEQ01">
        <title>Activity 3</title>
     </item>
     <imsss:sequencing>
        <imsss:controlMode choice = "false" flow = "true"/>
     </imsss:sequencing>
  </organization>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's correct. Notice that the primary objective "PRIMARYOBJ_2" is mapped to the global objective  "gObj-OB01a" which means "PRIMARYOBJ_1" and ""PRIMARYOBJ_2" have the same tracking data in terms of Satisfied Status.